I encountered the Janus file missing error while running a mail management program
I encountered the following error while running a mail management program, and unfortunately the program does not run.  The program installation file is not available to install again.  I also took the Janus file from the internet and replaced it during the program installation, but unfortunately the problem still persists.  (I guess this problem occurred after installing the firewall).  The program is only installed on one system and the database of the program is located on the server.  Thank you for your help to solve the problem.
